# How to configure interactive python to allow blank lines inside methods

Tags: python

Is it possible to test methods inside interactive python and retain blank lines within them?

```
def f1():
  import random
  import time

  time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
```

This gives the familiar error

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

So, yes a workaround is to remove all blank lines inside functions. I'd like to know if that were truly mandatory to be able to run in interactive mode/REPL.

thanks

Comment: Why do you need to add blank lines in the interpreter?  Are you copying and pasting?  By interpreter I assume you mean interactive python.

Comment: i think u have whitespace problems @FogleBird points out correctly, clean whitespaces, and carry on with blank lines no problems. You may use static analysis tools like 'pep8' which may show the warning for extra white spaces.

Comment: @SethMMorton; i corrected question to use verbage "interactive python".

Comment: @cool_n_curious:  Would you pls clarify about the whitespaces issue?  I have turned on 'view whitespace' in the editor and it clearly shows that if I add a one space character in the intervening line then this works, but otherwise get the indentation error.

Comment: after you changed it to "interactive python" my explanation goes reverse, with a witespace you are 'indenting things' in an interactive interpretter. when you leave a line without a whitespace you are in the same level of your function defination `def foo()` therefore you get errors as indentationError.

Comment: OK, think we're all on same page now and the answers have been helpful. I have simply added single space where i want to have some embedded blank lines within the procs, works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might not be much help, but it works if the blank lines are indented. Dots shown for clarity:

```
def f1():
....import random
....import time
....
....time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
```

Comment: Even a single space on the blank lines works; they don't need the full indentation.

Comment: I added single space and yes that work. thx!  btw if you think this were a reasonable question for me to ask, would you mind voting the question up? thx

Answer (score 0):

One option, especially for copy-pasting code into the interactive interpreter, is to embed it in a raw string literal and `exec` it:

```
exec(r'''
def f1():
  import random
  import time

  time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))''')
```

If the code you're entering already uses `'''` strings, surround it with `r"""..."""` quotes instead. If it already uses both `'''` and `"""`, this isn't going to work.